# How does Cauchy Reed-Solomon Algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, reference

Does anybody have any reference material that details Cauchy-Reed algorithm? Googling for Cauchy-Reed Solomon results [cleversafe.org](http://cleversafe.org). Although they have an open sourced  product based on Cauchy Reed-Solomon code, they haven't provided any material explaining how the algorithm works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Professor James Plank at UT (of the east) has a nice [explanation](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-05-569.pdf) and an efficient implentation.