# How best to split a file into N parts with M redundant parts such that any N of the N+M parts is sufficient to reconstuct it?

Tags: algorithm, channel, redundancy

Looking for the best algorithm to take a file, split it into N parts, add M redundancy parts and then store the file in N+M different locations.  Files would typically be large.

For example:  a 1GB file could be split into (32) 32MB parts, have (8) additional 32MB parts computed, and the 1.25GB redundant structure stored out on 40 different areas. The goal would be to recreate the file from any (32) valid parts. An independant hash of the original (32) parts would be available for sanity checking correct reconstruction.

If this is doable, I believe this would provide the functional equivalent of having 8 mirror copies for an overhead of only 25% (plus computation time), would it not?

I found the 1989 Rabin algorithm which appears to do this.  Was wondering if anyone was aware of something better/faster?

I recognize this is similar to how Raid 5 and Raid 6 work - looking to take that approach, extend it to 8+ parity blocks, and perform it at the file level.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about [secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing), I think you meant Rabin's algorithm?  Is there something that leads you to believe anyone's improved on that?

Comment: Did you refer to this article? http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~yavuza/Courses/Fall2014_AdvNetSec/ResearchPapers/RegularPapers/IDA.pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252555/how-does-cauchy-reed-solomon-algorithm-work seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo.  Rabin's approach in his 1989 IDA article is what I'm looking for.  Was under the impression reading that article that his approach is different thatn say Shamir's secret sharing.

Comment: Also thanks for the Cauchy-Reed thread, reading that now.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've defined the problem is indeed called secret sharing, but there have been improvements made since 1989 -- we no longer have to specify M in advance.

Now, you can generate an essentially limitless sequence of blocks for a file, and regenerate the file from *any* collection of them as long as their lengths add up to the length of the original file.

It's called a "fountain code": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_code .  The "raptor codes" are the best today, I believe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raptor_code .  They were the first to provide linear time encoding and decoding.

Note that raptor codes are not entirely reliable -- occasionally you may need to collect an extra block -- but for the use cases they support that's a small price to pay for linear time decoding.

If you need to be absolutely sure that you can decode the message given the minimal number of blocks, then I've found that secret sharing using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_theorem), but using irreducible polynomials in GF(2^N) instead of prime integers, extends easily into a fountain code, but requries (N^2) time to encode and decode.

Comment: So this link:  http://blog.notdot.net/2012/01/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Fountain-Codes provides a good high-level overview even I could understand.  Are their public domain raptor algorithms?  Or should I stick with the LT code described there and avoid stepping on any patents?  Performance is not my primary concern since use in my application might be on a daily, not minute-by-minute, basis.

Comment: RaptorQ is an IETF standard raptor code that is used in many places these days:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6330 .  There are lots of free implementations around, like http://openrq-team.github.io/openrq/ and http://openrq-team.github.io/openrq/

Comment: Thanks!  I'm reviewing the links now.  In my idealized application, I would be able to process a 1GB stream as (32) 32mb blocks, plus at least 8 spares.  Fountain coding, of course, makes the spare count trivial, and in fact would enable my end-user to specify as many as they cared to pay the transmission and end-point storage cost for.  Although this is easily met by the F, Z & N fields (transfer length (32mb + header), number of source blocks (32), number of sub-blocks(40)), I'm concerned about T - Symbol size, which appears to be limited to 64kb?  Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I could have 512 symbols per block, although that is not recommended, to achieve my 32mb block size (using round math that ignores packet headers).

Comment: You can put as many blocks as you want in each piece of that 1GB stream.